# Problemas con form array angular

Tags: array, angular, formularios, angular-reactive-forms

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario donde tengo 3 campos normales y un formarray para agregar n personas, el problema con el que me estoy encontrando es que al momento de agregar el grupo al array no me reconoce los valores que le estoy poniendo e incluso no me respeta las validaciones que le estoy mandando

```
export class FormCuestionarioFideicomisoComponent implements OnInit {

  error = false
  nuevoCuestionario: FormGroup

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm()
  }

  private initForm() {

    this.nuevoCuestionario = this.fb.group({

      tx_nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]$/)]],
      tx_ap_paterno: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/gm)]],
      tx_ap_materno: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/gm)]],
      fideicomitentes: this.fb.array([]),
    })
  }

  get fideicomitentes(): FormArray {
    return this.nuevoCuestionario.get("fideicomitentes") as FormArray
  }

  newFideicomitentes(): FormGroup {

    var tx_nombreF = 'carlos'
    var tx_ap_paternoF = 'ballarta'
    var tx_ap_maternoF ='gonzales'
    var tx_nacionalidad=1
    var tx_razon_social=1

    return this.fb.group({
      tx_nombreF: [tx_nombreF, [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]$/)]],
      tx_ap_paternoF: [tx_ap_paternoF, [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/gm)]],
      tx_ap_maternoF: [tx_ap_maternoF, [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/gm)]],
      tx_nacionalidad: [tx_nacionalidad, Validators.required],
      tx_razon_social: [tx_razon_social, [Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]$/)]],
    })
  }


  addFideicomitentes() {
    this.fideicomitentes.push(this.newFideicomitentes());
  }

  removeFideicomitentes(i: number) {
    this.fideicomitentes.removeAt(i);
  }


  get f() { return this.nuevoCuestionario.controls; }
  get f2() { return this.fideicomitentes.controls }


}
```

En el HTML cuando le doy agregar , se agregan las veces que yo le de sin problema solo que la primera vez lo inserta solo con el valor del nombre a pesar de que le doy mas valores en los demás campos y las demás veces vacío

mi código HTML es el siguiente

```
<form (ngSubmit)="Submit()" [formGroup]="nuevoCuestionario">

  <h1>CUESTIONARIO PARA LA COTIZACIÓN DEL FIDEICOMISO</h1>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    </button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" [ngClass]="!nuevoCuestionario.valid   ? 'btn-secondary' : 'btn-success'">Enviar
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-size: 15px;">Limpiar </button>

  </div>
  <div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.tx_nombre.errors && error==true}" autocomplete="off"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="tx_nombre" aria-describedby="tx_nombre-error"
          aria-invalid="true">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.tx_ap_paterno.errors && error==true}" autocomplete="off"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido paterno" formControlName="tx_ap_paterno"
          aria-describedby="tx_ap_paterno-error" aria-invalid="true">

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.tx_ap_materno.errors && error==true}" autocomplete="off"
          class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido materno" formControlName="tx_ap_materno"
          aria-describedby="tx_ap_materno-error" aria-invalid="true">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p style="padding-left: 15px;">Datos de los Fideicomitentes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 10px;"
          (click)="addFideicomitentes()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></div>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="fideicomitentes">
      <div *ngFor="let fideicomitente of fideicomitentes.controls; let i=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f2[i].controls.tx_nombreF.errors && error==true}"
                autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="tx_nombreF"
                aria-describedby="tx_nombreF-error" aria-invalid="true">

            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f2[i].controls.tx_ap_paternoF.errors && error==true}"
                autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido paterno" formControlName="tx_ap_paternoF"
                aria-describedby="tx_ap_paternoF-error" aria-invalid="true">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.tx_ap_maternoF.errors && error==true}" autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido materno" formControlName="tx_ap_maternoF"
                aria-describedby="tx_ap_maternoF-error" aria-invalid="true">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 10px;"
                (click)="removeFideicomitentes(indice)"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <select class="form-control" formArrayName="tx_nacionalidad">
                <option [value]="null">Nacionalidad</option>
                <option [value]="1">Mexicana</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="tx_razon_social">
                <option [value]="null">Tipo persona</option>
                <option [value]="1">Física</option>
                <option [value]="2">Moral</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

ya probé creando un get para los controles y intentar ver si algo estoy mandando mal

`get f2() { return this.fideicomitentes.controls }`

Pero incluso si lo imprimo en consola los campos si traen la información que le mando en el .ts pero en el HTML no sale nada incluso intente capturar el error de la validación pero tampoco me lo reconoce

`[ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f2[i].controls.tx_nombreF.errors }`

espero puedan ayudarme a que la información se muestre bien y a comprobar la validación de los campos

Comment: Estás constantemente usando los mismos nombres para los campos de los formularios... los nombres deberían de ser únicos. La excepción es cuando intentas enlazar varios radiobutton para que actúen como grupo, que se les pone el mismo nombre. Con los campos de texto siempre deberían tener nombres diferentes. Antes que nada deberías arreglar esto, prueba a usar nombres añadiendo por ejemplo la longitud de valores actual del array: `tx_nombreF: [\`tx_nombreF${fideicomitentes().length}\`,...`

Comment: Los dos únicos fallos que veo a primera vista en tu formulario son : que estas usando la directiva `formArrayName` en el campo `tx_nacionalidad` cuando tendría que ser `formControlName`; y que no deberías usar la flag `/g` en las `Regexp` ya que puede dar falsos errores de validación como dice en la [documentacion](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern-matching-with-the-global-or-sticky-flag). Por lo demás todo parece correcto.